# How to use token authentication in laravel web page

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, jwt

I am trying to use JWT for laravel web page instead of session. so I made some changes.

1. Installed [jwt-auth](https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth) and [configure](https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth/wiki/Installation)
2. Then changed default guard as `api` in config/auth.php

   ```
   'defaults' => [
       'guard' => 'api',
       'passwords' => 'users',
   ],

   'guards' => [
       ...

       'api' => [
           'driver' => 'token',
           'provider' => 'users',
       ],
   ],
   ```

Now I am getting error

> (1/1) FatalErrorException Call to undefined method
>   Illuminate\Auth\TokenGuard::attempt() in AuthenticatesUsers.php (line
>   75)

How to fix this and start token authentication for laravel web page(blades not API).

Comment: Have you used `$ php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Tymon\JWTAuth\Providers\JWTAuthServiceProvider"` and also set a secret key in the config file??

Comment: yes I did : https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth/wiki/Installation#laravel-5

Comment: I think you need to use `['middleware' => 'auth:api']` in your routes. Try this and let me know the results!

Comment: Is it works for you??

Comment: It would work after authentication, but I am getting this error while authentication via laravel default scaffolding login page submission.

Comment: I think you need to set `['middleware' => 'jwt.auth']` Not sure but try it! May be fixed your error! :) Let me know if it works.

Comment: You need to use `'guard' => 'web'` instead of `'guard' => 'api'` in `auth.php` and this fixed your problem!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I found the solution** here : https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth/issues/860

In /routes/api.php - added a few basic authentication routes

```
Route::post('login', 'Auth\LoginController@login');

Route::get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    $user = $request->user();
    return dd($user);
})->middleware('auth:api');
```

In /app/http/Controller/auth/LoginController.php

and then override methods in login contoller

```
public function login(Request $request)
{
    $credentials = $request->only(["email","password"]);
    if ($token = $this->guard()->attempt($credentials)) {
        return $this->sendLoginResponse($request, $token);
    }

    $this->incrementLoginAttempts($request);
    return $this->sendFailedLoginResponse($request);
}

protected function sendLoginResponse(Request $request, $token)
{
    $this->clearLoginAttempts($request);

    return $this->authenticated($request, $this->guard()->user(), $token);
}

protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user, $token)
{
    setcookie("jwt_token", $token);
    return redirect('/');
    return response()->json([
        'token' => $token,
    ]);
}

protected function sendFailedLoginResponse(Request $request)
{
    return response()->json([
        'message' => "not found",
    ], 401);
}
```

Adding middleware `AddToken`

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $token = isset($_COOKIE["jwt_token"])?$_COOKIE["jwt_token"]:"";
    //$request['token'] = $token;//this is working
    $request->headers->set("Authorization", "Bearer $token");//this is working
    $response = $next($request);
    //$response->header('header name', 'header value');
    return $response;
}
```

Register middleware in Kernel.php

```
 protected $middleware = [
    ....
    \App\Http\Middleware\AddToken::class,
];
```

Comment: Wonderful suggestion @C2486 works as a charm. In the LoginController (web) I've added at ´authentificated(...)´ ´$token = auth()->attempt($credentials);´ and ´setcookie('jwt_token', $token);´ and at LogoutController ´getLogout()´ ´return redirect()....->withCookie(\Cookie::forget('jwt_token'));´

Answer (score 2):

I'm also using jwt protecting our api. You should change your config like below:

```
'defaults' => [
    'guard' => 'api',
    'passwords' => 'users',
],

'guards' => [
    ...

    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'jwt', // KEY POINT!!!
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
],
```

Make sure the jwt library installed correctly:

1. Tymon\JWTAuth\Providers\LaravelServiceProvider::class is added in your config/app.php.
2. Your user model implements JWTSubject interface if you use eloquent model in your provider.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try this :

```
'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'web',
        'passwords' => 'users',
    ],

'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'token',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
```

**EDIT**

You can find some help from the [step by step example](https://scotch.io/tutorials/token-based-authentication-for-angularjs-and-laravel-apps). In this example you need to focus on how to configure and use that token base authentication.

Hope this help you well.

Comment: I want to use token authentication not session.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer this [link](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/issue-with-auth-receiving-undefined-method). If you are using api as default then laravel authentication will throw an error.

Comment: Yes boss I am getting this error. So what you suggest ?

Comment: revert back to `'defaults' => [
    'guard' => 'web',
    'passwords' => 'users',
],`

Answer (score 0):

Laravel uses default Session based authentication out of the box with the default scaffolding users-view-controller that you already have. You have additional means of adding your own [custom guard in the doc](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authentication#adding-custom-guards), so you can make use of the guard as needed.

Therefore as @KevinPatel suggested, revert back to the default configuration, then in your route: group the route you want to be under JWT authentication, add the JWTMiddleware, in this case you have to update the controller responsible for your authentication to use the JWTAuth instead of the default auth.

You should check this answer if you need to understand it better check [this answer on Laracasts](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/issue-with-auth-receiving-undefined-method/replies/302807)

One recommended way to [incorporate the JWTAuth](https://github.com/dingo/api/wiki/Authentication) is to go for [Dingo API](https://github.com/dingo/api) (of course you are not building api, but) because Dingo already added some flesh to the authentication and other routes management - so things are pretty easy to use and configure